# Как вытащить переменную из функции

Tags: javascript, node.js

Существует функция

```
async function getRegistryValues() {
     const RegistryValues = await Registry.get('HKCU\\Software\\XLauncher Client')
     console.log(RegistryValues.$values)
}
```

Которая выдает в консоль список значений из реестра в виде:

```
 { '(�� 㬮�砭��)': '', clubid: 'clubid', pcnum: 1 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращать на странные значения внимания не нужно, мне интересны последние 2 значения.

Мне требуется вытащить значение RegistryValues.$values.clubid и RegistryValues.$values.pcnum

Но вытащить переменную из функции просто так нельзя, и при изменении кода до:

```
async function getRegistryValues() {
    const RegistryValues = await Registry.get('HKCU\\Software\\XLauncher Client')
}
console.log(RegistryValues.$values)
```

Появляется ошибка

```
ReferenceError: RegistryValues is not defined
```

Что логично, ведь функция изолирует это значение, но где то далеко в душе я понимаю что нужное мне действие можно выполнить по другому))) просто я не знаю как. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: RegistryValues объявляется внутри функции и будет доступен только там. Если вам нужно значение внутри функции, вам нужно сделать логику возврата из функции нужными вам значениями.

Comment: Проблема в том что оно мне нужно вне функции, внутри функции оно прекрасно работает

Answer (score 0):

`return` Решает вашу проблему)

```js
async function getRegistryValues() {
    const RegistryValues = await Registry.get('HKCU\\Software\\XLauncher Client')
    return { 
      clubid: RegistryValues.clubid,
      pcnum: RegistryValues.pcnum
    }
}

getRegistryValues().then(data=>{
  console.log(data)
})
```

Чтобы тестировать я использовал ответ от

> списка значений из реестра

> `{ '(�� 㬮�砭��)': '', clubid: 'clubid', pcnum: 1 }`

```js
function getRegistryValues() {
    const RegistryValues = {
      '(�� 㬮�砭��)': '',
      clubid: 'clubid',
      pcnum: 1
    }
    return { 
      clubid: RegistryValues.clubid,
      pcnum: RegistryValues.pcnum
    }
}

const data = getRegistryValues()
console.log(data)
```

Comment: выдает Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Я не тестировал в своем реестре, поэтому добавил в ответ свой тестовый подход

Comment: Перепроверьте пожалуйста мой код на вашем ПК

Comment: Сразу в основном коде и проверил

Comment: ответ тот же? Или изменился что то?)

Comment: тот же. промис только в асинхронной функции как я понял может быть, обернул ваш ответ в асинхронную функцию

(async () => {
    const values = await getRegistryValues()
    console.log(values)
  })()

Выдало верные значения

{ clubid: 'clubid', pcnum: 1 }

Comment: Да-да, забыл поставить async перед функцией в ответе, потом исправил, но без этой обертки код точно должен работать. Поэтому же сказал перепроверьте))

Comment: заменил данные на вывод из реестра напрямую. без async функции хоть убейся undefined. но если использовать async не получится вывести переменную вне) эх, кажись придется искать костыли

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете? winreg?

Comment: rage-edit. winreg еще не видел, изучу

Comment: да не надо учить))) сейчас исправлю код. вроде заработает

Comment: Перепроверили?)

Comment: { clubid: undefined, pcnum: undefined }

Comment: измените код и отправьте ответ ->  const RegistryValues = await Registry.get('HKCU\\Software\\XLauncher Client')
    return { 
      ...RegistryValues,
    }